# swap directories - shell - using cp/mv

Tags: shell

I would like to swap directories.

The existence directory is for example:

```
 football  
    -league            - champions league
       --year             --2018
          ---players         ---
            ---- trophies      ----
```

I would like to swap the directories year and league and save it to a new directory.

```
The expected outcome is.:
  soccer  
    -year              - 2018
       --league            --champions league
          ---players         ---
            ---- trophies      ----
```

I tried following.:

```
mkdir soccer/
            for i in football/*; do
                    if [ -d "$i" ]; then
                            cp -r  football/*/*  soccer/
                            rm -r soccer/*/*
                            cp -r football/* soccer/*/
                            echo "DIR $i"
                    fi
            done
```

It didn't work - I am new to it - Can you please help?

Comment: Please be more specific. What exactly happens with your code?
Also, with the command `tree` you can print directory structures more clearly.

Comment: `mkdir -p soccer/year soccerr/2018` `mv football/league/year soccess/year/league` `mv football/chamions\ league/2018 soccess/2018/chamipons\ league`???

Comment: Thanks for your answers. cp -r  football/*/*  soccer/ : should copy all folders + files, which are in the directory year - to the directory soccer/. Is there a simple method to swap two directories?

Comment: So If I click on the directory (or folder) year, it should show me the directory league (or all folders of the directory league).  rm -r soccer/*/* is deleting all the folders + files of the directory league.cp -r football/* soccer/*/ is trying to copy everything from league of the directory football to the directory soccer/year/league, but it fails.I hope someone can help.